# how to php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Tags: upgrade

i want to add payment gateway, and i've to follow these steps.

but i don't know how to

> **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

[image: 3rd step]

3rd step
i tried but so Difficult

Comment: have you got solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to execute this command in a console, from the root directory of your magento.

```
cd magento_root/
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Don't forget to change "magento_root" by the real path to the root directory of your magento.